# jQuery function to open link in new window on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I would like a function that opens a link in a new window on mobile.
 
I have this script in jQuery, only works for Desktop.

How would this script for mobile?

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="mha">google</a>

<script> 
 $('.mha').click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=2000,height=2000,scrollbars=yes,fullscreen=yes");
 });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a7qJt/

Comment: Write `_blank` instead of `popupWindow`..

Comment: Should work on mobile too. Check whether popups are blocked. Try adding `target="_blank"` to `<a>`

Comment: Did not work. You can put a demo of _blank. @BrijeshBhatt

Comment: @ShaunakD How would this jquery script if it were to open in a new tab, without touching the <a>

Answer (score 0):

Add your event inside [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function and try.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
       window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=2000,height=2000,scrollbars=yes,fullscreen=yes");
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write only this much:

```
window.open($(this).attr("href"), "_blank");
```